# Neo4J always defaults NodeJS numbers as float when using parametrized queries

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to use the Neo4j with NodeJS, using parameters to save some values into a Neo4j node, something like this:

```
{
    query: 'MATCH (n{id:$id}) SET n.n1 = $number RETURN n',    
    params: { id: 'someId', number: 15 } 
}
```

When I view the data in Neo4j, the data always appears as `{n1: 15.0}` rather than `{n1: 15}`. Is there an easy way to keep the numbers as integers unless there's an explicit decimal in the number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `TOINTEGER()` function to convert to an integer:

```
MATCH (n{id:$id}) SET n.n1 = TOINTEGER($number) RETURN n
```

[UPDATED]

If you are using the official [neo4j Javascript driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver), then you should read up on its [special support for integers in Javascript](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#a-note-on-numbers-and-the-integer-type) (to work around the fact that Javascript does not support 64-bit integers, as used by neo4j).

In your case, you should use the driver's `neo4j.int()` method to pass an integer parameter value, otherwise it will be passed as a float.

For example:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

var result = session.run(
  "MATCH (n{id:$id}) SET n.n1 = $number RETURN n",
  {id: 'abc123', number: neo4j.int(15)}
);
```

Comment: Is that the only way? It's quite troubling since JS does not distinguish between integers and floats. It seems like if I did not use the parametrized query method it interprets the numbers correctly, but always sets them as floats when using parameters

Comment: Are you seeing that behavior when using node.js? Or just in the neo4j browser?

Comment: only in node.js, and presumably only when you use parametrized queries. I think it's related to the fact that js doesn't distinguish between ints and floats, but the weird thing is that it seems to work if I run a non-parametrized query

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: I believe it's the official neo4j driver: `import neo4j from "neo4j-driver"`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to define the type that I'm setting in the neo4j node schema then... Too bad, I was hoping I could avoid that.